# Firebase - how to create A/B test experiment for web app (not native app)

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I'd like to A/B test a feature on our web app, which uses Firebase.  When setting up the A/B test, I noticed that it's requiring me to select an "app" (I also have a native app), but I'm trying to **target users** that are using my **web app**.

[image]

One workaround I can think of is:

- create a remote config boolean variable
- add a condition to the variable for "user within random percentile"
- fetch that remote config value when the web app loads
- show/don't show feature based on the variable value

The downside of the workaround is that it won't track the Improvement or Experiment results, such as the following:
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to run a firebase A/B test **experiment** **for a web app**? (not native app)

Comment: I have exactly the same question

Comment: Have you found another technology that solved this issue for you?

Comment: @RubenSzekér I've recently come across [StatSig](https://statsig.com/) which seems to cover a/b testing, dynamic config, and feature flags. I like that they have both a free tier and then PAYG pricing on volume. I haven't tried them yet but I plan to, having found that Firebase falls short for web apps here.

Answer (score 4):

[Firebase A/B Testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing) is currently available for Android and iOS app. You may file a feature request on Firebase [support](https://firebase.google.com/support) portal for this.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase A/B testing is only available for iOS and Android. You can check other tools [like GrowthBook](https://www.growthbook.io/)